# UISlider thumb animation to get back to specified position when user interaction finishes

Tags: ios, iphone, uislider

I guess it is a very easy question to ask but I searched a lot but did not get any satisfactory answer or solution yet.

I am using a `UISlider` with its delegate:

```
 [slideroutlet addTarget:self
           action:@selector(sliderDidEndSliding:)
 forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)];


- (void)sliderDidEndSliding:(NSNotification *)notification {   
if(slideroutlet.value >= 1)
{

    if(slideroutlet.value < 1.630)
    {
        [slideroutlet setValue:1.107 animated:YES];
            [slideroutlet setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar-i.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
}
```

like set the rage of slider from 1 to 7 and if user intrection finishes between 1 and 1.630 then it should have to return to 1.107 position.
as code is working fine but the animation to move to this positon is moving too fast.

i searched and tried the below method and it worked but it is adding one more animation like at the time of getting back to the position slider is coming smoothly but the background image of slider is compressing to that position then restoring again

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
            [slideroutlet setValue:1.107 animated:YES];
            [slideroutlet setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar-i.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you limit the position in the first place, so the thumb never moves to an invalid position?

Comment: hello sir, actually i am creating a system in which i have 7 different positions on the sliders. And user have to select any to that position according to its requirement(completed this part). But the issue right now is this if user stopes the slider in between any two positions then i have to nearby position and move the slider thumb to the position smoothly(right now working properly but moving fast). So that atlest one of the choise user made have to be selected before going forward.  =>indly check i added the screenshot

Comment: So why don't you snap to each valid position while the user is sliding, then the user is clear on what is available and you don't need an animation?

Comment: Actually i am thinking that if user dint nit snap to at valid palce and leave the slider thumb in middle of two positions then the slider thumb is moving fast to the nearby position. thats why i am looking to for a solution to make it move little bit slow.    Thanks a lot for you valuable response and comment , i tried run the code on device for live testing it is not that fast as it is looking on simulator. it served the purpose for now. Thanks again.